# Почему у некоторых висящих процессов LastBatch равен 01/01 00.00.00?

Tags: sql-server

При выполнении SP_WHO2 замечаю некоторые висящие процессы у которых LastBatch равен 01/01 00.00.00. Почему такое происходит и как с этим бороться? Влияет ли это на что-нибудь вообще?

Comment: Судя по документации LastBatch это последнее время когда сеанс вызывал какую нибудь хранимую процедуру. А нулевое время тогда должно говорить о том, что никаких хранимых процедур данный сеанс не вызывал. и это абсолютно нормально

Comment: @Mike Мой код в прошлом вопросе убивал процессы по LastBatch, это самый эффективный параметр или есть параметр по которому будет более лучший эффект? Не знаю, время ожидание например какое-нибудь?

Comment: Учитывая что убийство процессов основную проблему все равно не решает никакой параметр не даст то, что нужно. я бы все таки посмотрел на sleeping процессы, держащие блокировки.

Comment: @Mike Я с вами согласен, но сейчас люди в ней уже работают, нету программистов кто-бы этим занялся, нужно получить хотя-бы временное решение этой проблемы, пускай это будет и закрытие процессов, без разницы, главное что-бы люди смогли нормально работать. Можете подсказать как лучше и быстрее решить эту проблему? Может Вы смогли бы изменить тот мой код под мои нужды? А если получится то будем смотреть дальше.

Comment: @Mike Делаю дефрагментацию индексов и их реиндексацию, ещё чистка кэша каждые 5 минут, это помогает, но не тогда когда висят процессы (наверно их ещё и заблокировал сервер), я поставил чистку процессов более 5 минут по LastBatch но это приносит не такой эффект как хотелось бы. Были замечены случаи потери информации и потери (ошибка главного окна при выходе) нужных процессов, т. е. не то что нужно, хотя это помогает. Что можно сделать в этой ситуации? Может какая-то оптимизация БД которую я не упомянул выше?

Comment: @Mike Вообще, вроде бы как, несколько лет назад, когда не было большого объёма информации, программа работала отлично. Хотя и сейчас информации на несколько гигабайт но есть проблемы. Программист говорил что программе выполняются лишние действия, например при сохранении накладной идёт пересчёт остатков по складу и т п.

Comment: проблема то в том что все процессы нужны. это же коннекты тех самых пользователей. я бы предложил бы искать бездействующие свыше определенного времени процессы, держащие блокировки. с другой стороны совершенно не ясно что у вас за такая странная ситуация при которой помогает очистка кеша. эта очистка по хорошему ни на что не влияет только возможно некоторые процессы которым был нужен кеш работают несколько дольше. для начала надо знать что именно не так что бы принимать какие то меры. а это вы не говорите, видимо потому что сами не знаете

Comment: @Mike Чистка кэша помогает не всегда. Насколько я врубился, использование планов из кэша бывает намного дольше (до 30 сек) чем создание новых (быстро). А когда висят процессы то помогает только их закрытие. Я так и поставил закрывать процессы по LastBatch свыше 5 минут. Но как я уже говорил есть потери информации и закрытие нужных процессов, а так же я замечал появление процессов после которых программа у всех начинает висеть, а это значит он будет активен 5 минут пока скрипт его не закроет, а если поставить каждую минуту то будет ещё большее закрытие нужных процессов.

Comment: если все висят и ждут одного значит проблема явно в блокировках. надо вручную при такой ситуации выявить виновный процесс, посмотреть какой SQL запрос он выполняет в данный момент. если он ничего не выполняет - значит проблема в отсутствии commit. если же выполняет, то вероятно он что то делает слишком медленно и оптимизация его запроса поможет в будущем. может ему какого индекса не хватает для быстрой работы ... посмотрите все тяжелые запросы в системе, http://www.sql.ru/blogs/decolores/946 посмотрите почему они тяжелы, из загрузки CPU или ввода-вывода. а уже исходя из этого решать

Comment: к убиванию процессов можно переходить только тогда, когда вы найдете чем именно отличаются самые неприятные из них. а это без детального ручного изучения блокировок сделать нельзя. если найдете что то что блокирует, на основе этого (наличия таких блокировок как они делают) можно уже описывать условия для авто-убивалки

Comment: И да, если раньше все было хорошо, а с течением времени все хуже и хуже, то скорее всего проблема все таки именно в долго работающих запросах долго удерживающих блокировки. и решается только внимательным разбором планов выполнения таких запросов и их оптимизацией. а оптимизация может быть как средствами бд (постройка дополнительных индексов), так и модификацией самого sql-запроса

Comment: Был у меня случай, я заметил по графикам загрузки жестких дисков, что с какого то момента нагрузка сильно возросла, я довольно долго забивал на проблему но нагрузка с того момента еженедельно становилась все выше и выше ... Оказалось, что был один не особо важный запрос, собиравший статистику по одной таблице, причем его интересовали данные за последние 5 минут. Но из за отсутствия индекса по дате он шел полным перебором таблицы. Пока таблица целиком умещалась в ОЗУ (а это продолжалось пару лет) все было отлично и не заметно, а вот когда перестала он начал жутко грузить диск.

Comment: @Mike Все не висят а запросы выполняются намного дольше. Хотя это только мои наблюдения. Когда висят какие-то процессы - запросы выполняются долго, нету этих процессов - всё хорошо.

Comment: могли бы сами погуглить между прочим. вот кстати интересную статью нашел https://habrahabr.ru/post/216309/

Comment: @mike После вашей ссылки сразу ее нашел)